# Expected behavior in cats-effect for exceptions thrown in `.delay` or `.map`

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

During a PR review, I was asked to replace `Sync[F].delay` with `Sync[F].catchNonFatal` because an exception *might be thrown*.

This does work:

```
scala> Sync[IO].delay(throw new Exception).recover{ case t: Throwable => 42 }.unsafeRunSync
res10: Int = 42
```

Not being sure if that behavior was specific to `IO`, I was also able to find the [corresponding law saying it's actually expected](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/master/laws/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/laws/SyncLaws.scala#L33), but I could not find mentions in the main cats-effect documentation about automatic handling of exceptions in the API.

Does anybody know the rationale and the expected behavior followed by cats-effect w.r.t. exceptions thrown in `.delay` or `.map` or `.flatMap`?

Comment: I'd take the laws as authoritative here, which means `delay` and `suspend` must catch ambient exceptions, while `map` and `flatMap` may or may not, depending on the instance (and whether they do or not for any given instance is likely only to be documented in some GitHub issue somewhere, unfortunately).

Comment: …anyway your reviewer was wrong. There are reasons you might prefer `catchNonFatal`, but they have to do with when evaluation happens, not how exceptions are handled.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, it's guaranteed by the laws that `delay` catches exceptions - that's an important part of the API and it would be very hard to use if that weren't true.

As for `map` and `flatMap`, there are no law-based guarantees that exceptions are caught in those methods - those methods are defined in the `Functor` and `FlatMap` typeclasses, not cats-effect. They expect pure functions, and catching thrown exceptions isn't referentially transparent.

However in practice, for `IO` specifically, exceptions *are* caught as part of the `IO` type's contract. But it's never ideal to rely on it for generic code.

So, don't write code like

```
IO(blah).map(a => mightThrow(a))
```

Instead write

```
IO(blah).flatMap(a => Either.catchNonFatal(mightThrow(a)).liftTo[IO])
```

Ideally the `mightThrow` method would return an `Either` instead of throwing, if it's otherwise not side-effecting